# Typescript: How to define a type for unknown quantity of record patterns

Tags: reactjs, typescript, types, nivo-react, index-signature

I'm trying to use Nivo charts with typescript and I'm not sure how to define the type of data Nivo expects for their Bar Chart. ([https://Nivo.Rocks](https://nivo.rocks))

I've been trying to use

1. Object Index Signature  ... `{[Key: string]: string;}`
2. Record  utility type    ... `Record<string, string>`

A snippet of example data from Nivo is as folllows:

```
data = [
    {
        country: 'AD',
        'hot dog': 111,
        'hot dogColor': 'hsl(168, 70%, 50%)',
        burger: 19,
        burgerColor: 'hsl(123, 70%, 50%)',
        sandwich: 161,
        sandwichColor: 'hsl(91, 70%, 50%)',
        kebab: 199,
        kebabColor: 'hsl(347, 70%, 50%)',
        fries: 153,
        friesColor: 'hsl(346, 70%, 50%)',
        donut: 41,
        donutColor: 'hsl(96, 70%, 50%)',
    }
];
```

I attempted things similar to this...

```
export type NivoBarData = {
    [Key: string]: string;
    [Key: string]: number;
    nodeKeyValue?: NivoBarNodeValue;
    nodeColor?: NivoBarNodeColor;
};

export type NivoBarTitle = Record<string, string>;
export type NivoBarNodeColor = { [Key: string]: string };
export type NivoBarNodeValue = { [Key: string]: number };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could improve the type by adding in the association of keys ending with `Color` to strings that represent colors using an intersection and template literal types:

```
type NivoDatum = {
    [key: `${string}Color`]: string;
} & {
    [key: string]: string | number;
};
```

Then it'll correctly error on incorrect types:

```
const datum: NivoDatum = {
    donut: 41,          // ok since it's not a color
    donutColor: 111111, // not a string
};
```

[Playground](https://tsplay.dev/wgQ5lm)

<sup>*Maybe I'll make a PR or open an issue about this later?*</sup>

Answer (score 0):

So...

There is an interface definition from Nivo called `BarDatum` and the `<ResponsiveBar/>` element takes `BarDatum[]` for its `data` prop.

The interface definition is as follows:

```
export interface BarDatum {
    [key: string]: string | number;
}
```

Comment: Really? I think they could make it better: https://tsplay.dev/WJXMRN

Comment: @caTS How would you make it better?

Is there a way to match the pattern like i was attempting with 
one title `Record<string, string>`
and an unlimited grouping of
keyXvalue `[Key: string]: number`
keyXcolor `[Key: string]: string`
keyY.... etc

Comment: I just linked a playground showcasing it... edit the `data` variable to see what behavior it has.

Comment: @caTS Cool! you even got the naming conventions matching the appended `[name]Color` pattern. Thank you!